# Where Can i find an emulator to test my operating system for ARMv8?

Tags: operating-system, arm, emulation, processor, armv8

I am currently writing an OS based on ARMv8 processor. I want to find an emulator that acts like the processor so I can see my OS working or not and to check my work.

I am on windows 10. are there any emulators recommended ?

I searched SO but no answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like QEMU version 2.1+ is what you want

> the latest version of upstream QEMU (2.1) now includes full ARMv8 system emulation support. This means that users can use upstream QEMU to run a full 64-bit ARMv8-A kernel and filesystem, such as a 64-bit Ubuntu cloud image. This was no small endeavour as it involved emulating a completely new instruction set, exception model, CPU implementation, and more. The implementation was verified with a custom instruction verification tool (RISU) and was heavily reviewed upstream by an engaged and incredibly supportive upstream QEMU community.

[source](https://www.linaro.org/blog/core-dump/running-64bit-android-l-qemu/)